# MS Access SQL: Don't Include in Count

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

Context: This is for a hypothetical car rental company. There are two tables concerned with this question. They are called 'Staff Table' and 'Sale Staff Member Table'. The first table includes information regarding staff members such as DOB and whatnot. The second table includes the following information:

[image]

Staff_ID = The Staff member's unique code
Sale_ID = The specific sale's unique code
SaleStaffMember_AssociatedWithPurchase = whether or not the staff member was involved with the initial sale or just the return of the car.

The two tables have the same Staff_ID.

I have written the following SQL:

```
SELECT [staff table].staff_id as [Staff ID], Count([sale staff member table].staff_id) AS [Number of Rentals]
FROM [staff table]
LEFT JOIN [sale staff member table] ON [sale staff member table].staff_id = [staff table].staff_id
WHERE [sale staff member table].staff_id IS NULL or [sale staff member table].staff_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [staff table].staff_id
```

What this does is that it lists every staff member (some staff members have not made any sales and hence are not in the sale staff member table) and beside them it lists the amount of sales they have made:

[image]

My issue is that the staff member pointed to here has technically NOT made any sales, however he is listed as having made 1 when he should have 0. I understand why, as i have not written anything concerning the associated with purchase field in the SQL. I tried doing so and the furthest I could get was completely removing that member from the query result. However, what I want to do is essentially say:

'If the staff member is not associated with the purchase, do not include this specific entry in the count'

But I have no idea how to do so. I tried a few ridiculous solutions and looked this up but I ultimately could not find a solution. I'm sure it's relatively simple, but I've just picked up SQL over the past few days so I do not know yet.

Edit: Just realised my where statement literally does nothing haha, but that doesn't solve anything, it just makes the code a bit neater:

my revised code:

```
SELECT [staff table].staff_id as [Staff ID], Count([sale staff member table].staff_id) AS [Number of Rentals]
FROM [staff table]
LEFT JOIN [sale staff member table] ON [sale staff member table].staff_id = [staff table].staff_id
GROUP BY [staff table].staff_id
```

Thanks!

Edit: FINAL ANSWER

```
SELECT [Staff Table].Staff_ID AS [Staff ID], SSM.[Number of Rentals] AS [Number of Rentals]
FROM [staff table] 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Staff_ID, nz(COUNT(Staff_ID),0) as [Number of Rentals] 
FROM [Sale Staff Member Table] 
WHERE SaleStaffMember_AssociatedWithPurchase = 1
GROUP BY Staff_ID) AS SSM
ON [Staff Table].Staff_ID = SSM.Staff_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, if you are just looking for staff members with associated purchase, then you could simply do this query:

```
SELECT s.staff_id AS [Staff Id], COALESCE(ssm.NoOfRentals,0) AS [Number of Rentals]
FROM [staff table] AS s 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT staff_id, COUNT(staff_id) as NoOfRentals 
FROM [sale staff member table] 
WHERE SaleStaffMember_AssociatedWithPurchase = 1
GROUP BY staff_id) AS ssm
ON s.staff_id = ssm.staff_id
```

please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This query will return all the staff members that have made sales and the number of sales they have made; however, what i want is a query which shows ALL staff members and the sales they have made, even if they are to be 0.

Comment: I should mention again, the query that i have above shows every staff member and their sale count, even if it is 0, but the one problem is that it shows that the staff member S000000976 has made a sale, even though he was not associated with the purchase. I want the query to not count where an id appears if the staff member is not associated with the purchase.

Comment: Please check the edited query if it can solve your problem.

Comment: I tried the edited query only to receive an error as you are not able to start a query with 'WITH'. I also tried just the second half of the query which got me the same result as i posted above. Edit: Just looked it up; turns out that access doesn't support WITH statements.

Comment: Also, i think it doesn't support 'ON' either.

Edit: i think i can create a workaround for those two problems but when i do i end up getting a syntax error

Comment: Your newly revised query returns the same result as I posted in my second image; the problem of association still persists. Also, I was wrong about ON, access definitely does support that.

Comment: I did try previously but my knowledge of subqueries is really bad, so i didn't get very far.

Comment: Please try this one, I didn't notice that you are using MS Access, sorry I was wrong.

Comment: This is veerrryy close to my ideal result, thankyou so much! It displays all the Staff IDs alongside the number of sales they have made but the one slight issue is that when they have made no sales, the field is null. If it is possible I would like the null fields to be equal to '0'.

Comment: I Figured it out; I'll post the code above, thankyou so much for all your help!

Comment: I've added COALESCE to take care of the NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to your initial query something like

```
Sales:sum (iif(SaleStaffMember_AssociatedWithPurchase = 1,1,0))
```

This will leave every staff member in the result and sum up the number of sales they are associated with.